# copy data from 2 separate tables in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Just wondering is it possible to extract data from 2 different tables at one time in postgresql

I have the following:

Blocks Table - has been created as follows in order to fit a schema, so the JSON information has all been stored in an information column containing 36 polygons each

| UUID (UUID) | Name (TEXT) | Type (TEXT) | Information (TEXT) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 815b2ce7-ce99-4d6c-b41a-bec512173f53 | C2 | Block | 'stored JSON info' |
| 7a9a03fc-8be6-47ca-b743-43715ebb5610 | D2 | Block | 'stored JSON info' |
| 9136dcda-2a55-4084-87c1-68ccde23aed8 | E3 | Block | 'stored JSON info' |

For a later query, I need to know the geometries of each of the polygons, so I created another table using a code which parsed them out:

```
CREATE TABLE blockc2_ AS SELECT geom FROM (SELECT elem->>'type' AS type, elem->'properties' AS prop, elem->'geometry' AS geom FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(data) elem FROM block) f1)f2;
```

A final table is created to show just the geometries (which will a associated with the already created UID's like below

new_table

| UUID (UUID) | Geometry (Geometry) |
| --- | --- |
| 815b2ce7-ce99-4d6c-b41a-bec512173f53 | 01030000000100000005000000972E05A56D6851C084D91C434C6C32401C05D4886B6851C086D974FA4D6C324078F4DA916D6851C036BF7504766C3240F31D0CAE6F6851C035BF1D4D746C3240972E05A56D6851C084D91C434C6C3240 |
| 7a9a03fc-8be6-47ca-b743-43715ebb5610 | 01030000000100000005000000BB05694F726851C0CB2A87A8486C32403EDC3733706851C0CD2ADF5F4A6C32409ACB3E3C726851C07E10E069726C324017F56F58746851C07C1088B2706C3240BB05694F726851C0CB2A87A8486C3240 |
| 9136dcda-2a55-4084-87c1-68ccde23aed8 | 1030000000100000005000000972E05A56D6851C084D91C434C6C32401C05D4886B6851C086D974FA4D6C324078F4DA916D6851C036BF7504766C3240F31D0CAE6F6851C035BF1D4D746C3240972E05A56D6851C084D91C434C6C3240 |

Ideally, I need a code like below (if its possible) because if I insert them separately they don't associate with each other. Instead of 3 rows of info, it will be 6 (3 UUIDS and 3 Geometries)

```
INSERT INTO new_table (uuid, geometry) SELECT UUID FROM blocks WHERE Name='C2' AND SELECT geometry FROM second_table WHERE Name='C2'
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

create table C (select * from table B union all select * from table A)

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't seem to be working for me though. I have the new table created, so I need to insert the individual columns from the individual tables (UUID from blocks, Geometry from second_table)

Comment: Also, I have tried this and get the error ERROR:  UNION types uuid and text cannot be matched

Answer (score 0):

This *sounds* like a `join`:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (uuid, geometry)
    SELECT b.UUID, g.geometry
    FROM blocks b JOIN 
         geometry g
         USING (name)
    WHERE Name = 'C2';
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this and unfortunately I can use the join as one column doesn't exist in the other. ERROR:  column "block_id" specified in USING clause does not exist in left table

Comment: @AmyOKeefe . . . `block_id` is not in the `USING` clause, so this answer cannot generate that error.

Comment: I altered your suggestion in order to fit my query